# Failed to load resource: PHP with jQuery callback

Tags: php, jquery, json

*PHP upgrade from 5.2 to 5.6 the below code stopped working:*

After Running it throwing the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error).
I am not sure if there is an issue with javascript or PHP itself that is causing the issue. The frontend is loading but it is not fetching the data on the callback.

Any help will be really appreciated. If this is a duplicate of some error or post, please point me towards a necessary answer. If I have done any mistake in writing the question, Please write a comment why are you doing that instead of just blatantly giving me a negative score.

Javascript snippet:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {        
            // Get data from Outlast Server
            var url="https://xxxxx/xxxx/q_data.php?callback=?";
            jQuery.getJSON(url,  function(rts_data) {
                var deck_count = 0, shiplap_count = 0, bnb_b_count = 0, bnb_c_count = 0;

                for(var i=0; i<rts_data.length; i++) {
                    if (rts_data[i].type == "Deck") {
                        data[0][deck_count] = new Object();
                        data[0][deck_count].productName = rts_data[i].productName;
                        data[0][deck_count].coverage    = rts_data[i].coverage;
                        data[0][deck_count].screws      = rts_data[i].screws;
                        data[0][deck_count].gaps        = rts_data[i].gaps;

                        // Insert the data into the Select Box
                        jQuery('#opt_d').append(jQuery('<option>', { value : deck_count }).text(rts_data[i].productName)); 

                        deck_count++;
                    }
                    else if (rts_data[i].type == "Shiplap") {
                        data[1][shiplap_count] = new Object();
                        data[1][shiplap_count].productName = rts_data[i].productName;
                        data[1][shiplap_count].coverage     = rts_data[i].coverage;
                        data[1][shiplap_count].screws       = rts_data[i].screws;
                        data[1][shiplap_count].gaps         = rts_data[i].gaps;

                        // Insert the data into the Select Box
                        jQuery('#opt_s').append(jQuery('<option>', { value : shiplap_count }).text(rts_data[i].productName)); 

                        shiplap_count++;
                    }
                    else if (rts_data[i].type == "Board and Batton - Cap") {
                        data[2][bnb_c_count] = new Object();
                        data[2][bnb_c_count].productName = rts_data[i].productName;
                        data[2][bnb_c_count].coverage   = rts_data[i].coverage;
                        data[2][bnb_c_count].screws         = rts_data[i].screws;
                        data[2][bnb_c_count].gaps       = rts_data[i].gaps;

                        // Insert the data into the Select Box
                        jQuery('#opt_bnb_c').append(jQuery('<option>', { value : bnb_c_count }).text(rts_data[i].productName)); 

                        bnb_c_count++;
                    }
                    else if (rts_data[i].type == "Board and Batton - Base") {
                        data[3][bnb_b_count] = new Object();
                        data[3][bnb_b_count].productName = rts_data[i].productName;
                        data[3][bnb_b_count].coverage   = rts_data[i].coverage;
                        data[3][bnb_b_count].screws         = rts_data[i].screws;
                        data[3][bnb_b_count].gaps       = rts_data[i].gaps;

                        // Insert the data into the Select Box
                        jQuery('#opt_bnb_b').append(jQuery('<option>', { value : bnb_b_count }).text(rts_data[i].productName)); 

                        bnb_b_count++;
                    }
                }
```

PHP:

```
<?php
// Connection data
$host = "xxxxxxx";
$username = "xxxxx";
$database = "xxxxx";
$password = "xxxxx";

// Opens a connection to a mySQL server
$connection = mysql_connect ($host, $username, $password);
if (!$connection) {
    die("Not connected : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the active mySQL database
$db_selected = mysql_select_db($database, $connection);
if (!$db_selected) {
    die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

// Set the where clause
$where = "";
switch(@$_GET['type']) {
    case 'shiplap':
        $where = "WHERE type = 'Shiplap'";
    break;

    case 'deck':
        $where = "WHERE type = 'Deck'";
    break;

    case 'bnb_base':
        $where = "WHERE type = 'Board and Batton - Base'";
    break;

    case 'bnb_cap':
        $where = "WHERE type = 'Board and Batton - Cap'";
    break;

    default:
        $where = "";
    break;
}

// Run the query
$query = "SELECT * FROM `site_products` {$where} ORDER BY productID ASC";
$result = mysql_query($query);

if (!$result) {
    die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}

// Declare Variables
$data_shiplap   = array();
$shiplap_i      = 0;

// Get the data and divide
while ($row = @mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $data_shiplap[$shiplap_i]['productName']    = $row['productName'];
    $data_shiplap[$shiplap_i]['coverage']       = $row['coverage'];
    $data_shiplap[$shiplap_i]['screws']         = $row['screws'];
    $data_shiplap[$shiplap_i]['gaps']           = $row['gaps'];
    $data_shiplap[$shiplap_i]['type']           = $row['type'];

    $shiplap_i++;
}

echo $_GET['callback']. '('. json_encode($data_shiplap) . ')'; 
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After PHP 5.6.* all `mysql_*` functions are deprecated. I think that's why you are getting the `Internal server error`. Replace all the `mysql_*` functions with `mysqli_*` and see if the error is persistent.

Comment: Thankyou RopAli Minshi. Your solution has helped me get rid of the error but it is still not fetching data from the database, am I doing something wrong in above PHP?

Comment: There is no Error in the DevTools regarding anything now.

Comment: I think you are following the same syntax of mysqli_connect() as mysql_connect() but there I think there is difference of parameters in mysqli_connect(). Use this syntax - mysqli_connect(host,username,password,dbname,port,socket);

Comment: Hi, Thank you for pointing me in right direction. I needed to change the syntax of 5.6 of mysqli on database connection and selection. I really appreciate your help.

Comment: Happy to help...:)